# How do I fix my algorithm from messing up my input in my choose your own adventure game?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, keyboard

I'm working on a choose your own adventure text game on python and I added an algorithm that makes it so if you press the H key your hunger is shown and if you press T the time left is shown. But when I run my code the script runs but after the first input option is entered for your name, the breakfast yes/no input question gets printed again and again no matter what is entered. When i delete my algorithm, it runs fine and goes into the next step. I know I probably made a very stupid mistake but I am fairly new and I would greatly appreciate it if I could get some help. Thank you!
My code:

```
import keyboard
hunger = 100
timeLeft = 100
yes_no = ["yes", "no"]
breakfast = ["eggs", "cereal"]
name = input("What is your name?\n")
print("Hello, " + name + "! This is the BREAKFAST STORY.")
answer = ""
while answer not in yes_no:
    answer = input("You wake up one morning and are very hunrgy, do you get breakfast? (yes/no?)")
    if answer == "yes":
        print("You enter the kitchen, your hunger gets worse every second.")
    elif answer == "no":
        print("You starve to death. The End!")
        quit()
answer = ""
while answer not in breakfast:
    answer = input("What do you eat? (eggs/cereal?)    ")
    if answer == "eggs":
        print("Good job! You fed yourself, you stayed alive and you live a happy life")
        quit()
    elif answer == "cereal":
        print("Sorry, the cereal was 10 years overdue, you die terribly!. Rest in peace,"+ name +".")
        quit()
#algorithm
if(keyboard.is_pressed('t')):
   timeLeftFunction()
elif(keyboard.is_pressed('h')):
       hungerFunction()

def timeLeftFunction():
    timeLeft -= 20
    print("TIME LEFT:"+timeLeft+"%")

def hungerFunction():
    hunger -= 30
    print("HUNGER"+"%")
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, this works perfectly as expected for me. Are you sure that you used this exact version of the code? Please check again and add some sample output.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Oh wow! I am so dumb that ended up working after running it again and again. Thank you for helping though! For some odd reason I had to close everything up and open it again and it was working fine again, I'm using the python IDLE tool.  Thank you again!!